# How to Select XML node, given only the attribute name

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file as follow

```
<NODE1 attribute1 = "SomeValue" attribute2 = "SomeOtherValue" />
<NODE2 attribute3 = "SomeValue" attribute4 = "SomeOtherValue" />
```

Now I am given only the attribute name say "attribute3". How can I get the name of node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following namespace at the top of your file:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

And try this (assuming that *input.xml* is the path to your XML file):

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
string nodeName;
var node = xml.Descendants()
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("attribute3") != null);
if (node != null)
    nodeName = node.Name.LocalName;
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var nodes = xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Attribute("attribute3") != null);
```

Or with XPath (as Marvin suggested):

```
var nodes = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//*[@attribute3]");
```

Both queries will return collection of `XElement` nodes which have attribute `attribute3` defined. You can get first of them with `FirstOrDefault`. If you want to get just name, use `node.Name.LocalName`.

UPDATE: I do not recommend you to use XmlDocument, but if you already manipulating this xml document, then loading it second time with XDocument could be inefficient. So, you can select nodes with XPathNavigator:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_xml);
var naviagator = doc.CreateNavigator();            
var nodeIterator = naviagator.Select("//*[@attribute3]");
```

Comment: I am already using XmlDocument to load XML and perform some other tasks.

Comment: Can I use both XMLDocument and XDocument

Comment: @imvarunkmr it's better to use XDocument if you are using .NET Framework 3 or later versions

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
    string nodeName;
    if(Node.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().Any(x => x.Name == "attribute3"))
    {
        nodeName=Node.Name;
    }
```